# nginx - owncloud under location

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I want to put owncloud under a location in my default virtual host.
I also want to redirect to https. I have got it working with phpmyadmin but i can't with owncloud.

This is the suggested configuration file form owncloud.org

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/localcerts/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/localcerts/privateKey.key;

        server_name cloud.technolust.info;

        root /var/www/owncloud;

        client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

        index index.php;
        error_page 403 = /core/templates/403.php;
        error_page 404 = /core/templates/404.php;

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
                deny all;
        }

        location / {
                # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
                rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
                rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

                rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
                rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

                rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

                try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {

        try_files $1 = 404;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
                fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
                expires 30d;
                # Optional: Don't log access to assets
                access_log off;
        }

}
```

i want some help in order to put the above configuration under the corresponding location in my default nginx virtual host. Here is my  **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  _;


    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    location /owncloud {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    location /cloud {
        rewrite ^/* /owncloud last;
    }

}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localcerts/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localcerts/privateKey.key;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }
    ######  phpMyAdmin ############################################################
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            root /usr/share/;
            include fastcgi-gen.conf;
        }
        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
        }
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    ######  OwnCloud ############################################################
    location /owncloud {
        *
        *
        CONFIGURATION HERE
        *
        *
    }
    location /cloud {
        rewrite ^/* /owncloud last;
    }
}
```

Also if you see anything else wrong with my configuration tell me as i am new to nginx.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think i got it working. The redirection seems to work also. I hope everything is correct. Here is my location /owncloud:

```
location /owncloud {
    root /var/www/;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;

    client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;


    # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

    rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

    error_page 403 = /var/www/owncloud/core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 = /var/www/owncloud/core/templates/404.php;

    location ~ ^/robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi-gen.conf;
    }
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
                    expires max;
    }
}
location /cloud {
    rewrite ^/* /owncloud last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The owncloud configuration assumes you use a virtual host, in the example `server_name cloud.technolust.info;` instead of a path `your current host/owncloud`

In order to use the path you need to replicate owncloud configuration inside the location (ie. your CONFIGURATION HERE section).

Comment: That's exactly what i am asking... I cant just copy-paste it there. It needs some changes. And that is exactly why i put the CONFIGURATION HERE.